# Why doesn't my @media screen save

Tags: html, css, media-queries, adobe-brackets

I have been stuck with this problem or the past hour and its really annoying me. I am making my website responsive to different screen sizes every time I write the code for it, I test it and it works. Then if I close the browser and reopen or reopen the code editor (brackets) the page loads like nothing happened. So I have re write everything again. This problem keeps recurring and I don't know why it wont just save. I can place my code since its over 2000 lines and I have just moved on to the responsive side of the site.

but I have applied this to every html file.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and I have used this as my starting statement for the @media in the css

```
@media screen and (max-width:)
```

**CSS**

```css
header img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

footer img{
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 40%;
    right: 40%;
}

.logo img{
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 40%;
    right: 40%;

}

.home img{
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 40%;
    right: 40%;
    width: 120px;
}


.socialmedia-twitter img {
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 20%;
    right: 40%;
}

.socialmedia-facebook img {
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 20%;
    left: 40%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px){

    header img{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
    }

    footer img{
        position:fixed;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        bottom: 5%;
        left: 40%;
        right: 40%;
    }

    .logo img{
        position:fixed;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        bottom: 2%;
        left: 40%;
        right: 40%;
    }

    .home img{
        position:fixed;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        bottom: 5%;
        left: 40%;
        right: 40%;
        width: 120px;
    }


    .socialmedia-twitter img {
        position:fixed;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        bottom: 5%;
        right: 50%;

    }

    .socialmedia-facebook img {
        position:fixed;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        bottom: 5%;
        right: 20%;
        left: 50%;
    }

}
```

Comment: That so strange, might sound like a stupid question but is the media query place below the rest of the css because your queries like good to me

Comment: yep it is, its so annoying i have re-write and then when im done it will happen again

Comment: Are you using brackets live preview or opening the .html file from the folder?

Comment: i did and i just checked the normal file and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Can you show me atleast one of your media queries?

Comment: sure. i will edit the post and show an example

Comment: ok let me know when you edited the question

Comment: I honestly don't know the problem as the the queries are all good, it must be some code messing with them. You could try linking a new style sheet below the rest of the css like - <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 640px)" href="small-device.css" /> that way we can work out whether its the saving or the code itself

Comment: thats so strange, i would make a new css file and save it separately to stop your constantly re-writing the code

Comment: Do you have any jQuery which is re-writing the css?

Comment: i had a file but i never really used it. I just linked it to the html but didnt use it.

Comment: I would defiantly re-post this when you can

Comment: here `@media screen and (max-width:) header img{` did you open curly brackets like this:  `@media screen and (max-width:) { header img{`  ?

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` - put in a width

Comment: daviestar i did put in a width and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of reasons why this could have happen, but i think it is the obvious one.
if you reach a sertan width @media screen and (max-width: 640px)
this css wil be enabled, in order to work his way back you need to define the width your working in.
While working on the design, it is also recommended to turn of any cache methods.

So for this to work proberly you will prob need three @media screen properties.

[Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)